# Using postgresql for Django under win7?

Tags: python, django, configuration, psycopg2

I am currently playing with django and want to use as my database postgresql:

[image]

and these are my configurations in my settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'postgres',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

I also tried it with postgresql_psycopg2 and also installed psycopg2(http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

Any ideas whats wrong with the configurations?

**UPDATE:**

The Error:

```
>   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
> line 382, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
> 196, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
> 232, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
> 371, in handle
>     return self.handle_noargs(**options)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py",
> line 57, in handle_noargs
>     cursor = connection.cursor()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line
> 15, in complain
>     raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. " django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
> value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Where do you specify what database should be used?  Because in your pgadmin screen I only see the postgres database which you should not use, it's used by the server for organisational purposes.

Comment: Also, using user postgres (the superuser aka root of the server) to interact with a database is ok for a quick test, but not something you should do in a real app.

Comment: @fvu Thx for your answer! I posted my error message from the django framework. It says that the ENGINE value is not right, why? Currently I am using the django db from my screenshot. Thx in advance!!!

Comment: Can you connect to the django database using a different client (e.g., `psql`)?

Comment: BTW `HOST` on Windows should be set to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, as an empty strings implies UNIX socket connection, which is on available on Windows. But that's hardly your problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I am adding an answer for future visitors. You seem to have several errors:

1. If you already installed psycopg2, you should change the `ENGINE` name to `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`.
2. In your settings you specified your database `NAME` to be `django`, but in your pgAdmin screenshot it is seen that you don't have such a database. Create a database named `django` using pgAdmin.

The correct setup would be then:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```